# How I can receive page summary by using Java?

Tags: java, timing, pageload, page-load-time, navigation-timing-api

I want to receive the next info about a web page:

- [TTFB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_To_First_Byte)
- Page load time
- Resources (css, js, img ...) load time

Required condition: all this info must be received in the one request.
Anybody have a solution of this problem on Java?

Comment: Read and process the web server logs, perhaps.

Comment: @Puh, this is the question. What need to load a page that would get the data?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc, I need receive this data programmatically.

Comment: Fine, since you used the Java tag, use a BufferedReader to read the web server logs.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc, I don't use a web server. I use the JavaSE.Tthere may be an external software allowing to obtain this data? Or another way, without the use of server logs?

Comment: I suppose you can use the [URLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) class to get a web page, and [HtmlUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) to process the web page.

Answer (score 1):

**TTFB:** open socket to the server. that gives to you the network latency + socket opening time. via that socket you should send http request. Moment when you will get http header - will be your TTFB... but... as i said - it contains network latency, also you can get redirect response, or protocol upgrade or wte. So you should analyse this.

**Page load time** if you get 200 response on previous stage - just load all data...

**Resources (css, js, img ...) load time** at this stage you will measure not a web servers performance and network latency, but also yours. you should parse received html, find all links to resources, and repeat first step (open socket) or download them via httpClient or smt else...

also you you should remember about http/2, gzip...